# Converting C++/opencv code to C

Tags: c++, c, opencv

How can I proceed to convert this C++ with OpenCV code to plain C ?

```
void sharpen(const Mat& src_, Mat& dst_) {

  dst_.create(src_.size(),src_.type());
  const int nChannels = src_.channels();

  unsigned int arr_len = nChannels*(src_.cols-1);
  for(int j = 1 ; j < src_.rows-1; ++j) {
    const uchar* previous_0 = src_.ptr<uchar>(j - 1);
    const uchar* current_0  = src_.ptr<uchar>(j    );
    const uchar* next_0     = src_.ptr<uchar>(j + 1);

    const uchar* previous_1 = src_.ptr<uchar>(j - 1)+3;
    const uchar* current_1  = src_.ptr<uchar>(j    )+3;
    const uchar* next_1     = src_.ptr<uchar>(j + 1)+3;

    const uchar* previous_2 = src_.ptr<uchar>(j - 1)+6;
    const uchar* current_2  = src_.ptr<uchar>(j    )+6;
    const uchar* next_2     = src_.ptr<uchar>(j + 1)+6;
    uchar* output = dst_.ptr<uchar>(j);

    for(unsigned int i=nChannels; i<arr_len; ++i) { // for k=2.25
      *output++ = saturate_cast<uchar>((12*(*current_1++) -(*current_0++) -(*current_2++)
                        -(*previous_1++) -(*previous_0++) -(*previous_2++)
                        -(*next_1++) -(*next_0++) -(*next_2++))/4);
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose to get the image into an array of uchar(0-255).
I have no problem converting **saturate_cast** template to C.

Comment: How is Mat declared?

Comment: Instead of Mat i'm declaring like this :
`guint8 *src, *dst;`
guint8 in a typedef for uchar

Comment: do you still have access to number of rows, cols and channels in your "instead of mat" version?

Comment: Yes I do, I know the number of rows, columns and channel.

Comment: How **Mat** stores information about the GrayScale or color byte image ?